# Is it bad practice to provide your own setter or should I use setproperty?

Tags: julia

Suppose if I had the following `Employee` `struct`:

```
mutable struct Employee
  _id::Int64
  _first_name::String
  _last_name::String
  
  function Employee(_id::Int64,_first_name::String,_last_name::String)
    # validation left out.
    new(_id,_first_name,_last_name)
  end
end
```

If I wanted to implement my own `setproperty!()` I can do:

```
function setproperty!(value::Employee,name::Symbol,x)
  if name == :_id
    if !isa(x,Int64)
      throw(ErrorException("ID type is invalid"))
    end
    setfield!(value,:_id,x)
  end
  if name == :_first_name
    if is_white_space(x)
      throw(ErrorException("First Name cannot be blank!"))
    end
    setfield!(value,:_first_name,x) 
  end
  if name == :_last_name
    if is_white_space(x)
      throw(ErrorException("Last Name cannot be blank!"))
    end 
    setfield!(value,:_last_name,x)
  end 
end
```

Have I implemented `setproperty!()` correctly?

The reason why I use `setfield!()` for `_first_name` and `_last_name`, is because if I do:

```
if name == :_first_name
  setproperty!(value,:_first_name,x) # or value._first_name = x 
end
```

it causes a `StackOverflowError` because it's recursively using `setproperty!()`.

I don't really like the use of `setproperty!()`, because as the number of parameters grows, so would `setproperty!()`.

It also brings to mind using [Enum and if statements](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300080/when-are-enums-not-a-code-smell) (only we've switched `Enum` with `Symbol`).

One workaround I like, is to document that the fields are meant to be `private` and use the provided `setter` to set the field:

```
function set_first_name(obj::Employee,first_name::AbstractString)
    # Validate first_name before assigning it.   
    obj._first_name = first_name
end
```

The function is smaller and has a single purpose.

Of course this doesn't prevent someone from using `setproperty!()`, `setfield!()` or `value._field_name = x`, but if you're going to circumvent the provided `setter` then you'll have the handle the consequences for doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Of course this doesn't prevent someone from using setproperty!(), setfield!() or value._field_name = x, but if you're going to circumvent the provided setter then you'll have the handle the consequences for doing it.

I would recommend you to do this, defining getter,setter functions, instead of overloading `getproperty/setproperty!`. on the wild, the main use i saw on overloading `getproperty/setproperty!` is when fields can be calculated from the data. for a getter/setter pattern, i recommend you to use the `!` convention:
getter:

```
function first_name(value::Employee)
  return value._first_name
end
```

setter:

```
function first_name!(value::Employee,text::String)
  #validate here 
  value._first_name = text
  return value._first_name 
end
```

if your struct is mutable, it could be that some fields are uninitialized. you could add a getter with default, by adding a method:

```
function first_name(value::Employee,default::String)
  value_stored = value._first_name
  if is_initialized(value_stored) #define is_initialized function
    return value_stored
  else
    return default
  end
end
```

with a setter/getter with default, the only difference between `first_name(val,text)` and `first_name!(val,text)` would be the mutability of `val`, but the result is the same. useful if you are doing mutable vs immutable functions. as you said it, the `getproperty/setproperty!` is cumbersome in comparison. If you want to disallow accessing the fields, you could do:

```
Base.getproperty(val::Employee,key::Symbol) = throw(error("use the getter functions instead!")

Base.setproperty!(val::Employee,key::Symbol,x) = throw(error("use the setter functions instead!")
```

Disallowing the syntax sugar of `val.key` and `val.key = x`. (if someone really want raw access, there is still `getfield/setfield!`, but they were warned.)

Finally, i found this recomendation in the julia docs, that recommends  getter/setter methods over direct field access
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Prefer-exported-methods-over-direct-field-access